# Binding Slider.Value to property and setting Value to value above Slider.Maximum will coerce it to Maximum but the ViewModel will go out of sync

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, coerce

Before I start to explain my problem: The `Slider` is just an example for the following problem. I work on a custom control, that has to do a very similar thing like the slider does here:

**Scenario:**

- I have bound a `Slider.Value` to my ViewModel property called `MyValue`.
- I have defined the `Maximum` of the `Slider` to be `100`.
- Now I set the Property `MyValue` to `200`.

**What is the problem?**

- The Slider will internally coerce the value to be 100.
- But the property `MyProperty` isn't being updated.
- In my case (the custom control I built), I need to continue with the coersed value (100) later on, NOT the old (200) value.

**Question:**

Is there anything I can do in my custom control?

For example I tried `myControl.GetExpression(MyValueProperty).UpdateSource();` in both my `CoerseValueCallback` and `PropertyChangedCallback`, but no matter what I try, the setter of the bound ViewModel-property is NEVER called and the property stays out of sync.

Comment: Limit the viewmodel property to the valid range otherwise throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, because the value is out of its supported range OR update your view because it does not support the whole range

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `Maximum` property of your `Slider` to another view model property and implement logic to ensure that your values are always within the valid range in your view model class.

The control rightfully coerces the values but the logic of synchronizing them should be implemented in the view model class.

Your custom control should be able to simply set the source property of its current `DataContext` whenever the value is coerced though.

`this.GetBindingExpression(Slider.ValueProperty).ResolvedSourcePropertyName` should give you the name of the source property and then you can for example set it using reflection if calling `UpdateSource()` on the `BindingExpression` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had hoped it would work without moving the validation to the viewmodel / other layers.